# Como cambio el valor de una variable?

Tags: php

el caso es que quiero capturar 2 variables por POST y que un grupo de if elseif las comparen. Ejemplo

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
$var3 = 0;

if ($var1 == 1 && $var2 == 2){
            $var3++;
}
?>
```

El problema es que quiero que el valor de la variable cambie permanentemente en caso de que el if arroje un booleano TRUE, ya que así al recargar la página la $var3 vuelve a 0.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo recomendaria es que esa variable la mandes por `GET` para que el valor nunca cambie y siempre permanezca como dices `permanentemente`.

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
$var3 = $_GET[valor];

if ($var1 == 1 && $var2 == 2){
            $var3++;
}
?>
```

tu `url` debe ir mas o menos así: `www.localhost.com/?valor=0`.
Si tu pagina se actualiza:

```
$pageRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) &&($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0' ||  $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] == 'no-cache'); 
if($pageRefreshed == 1){
    header('Location: localhost.com/?valor='+$var3);
}
```

Comment: La $var3 es una variable predefinida de valor 0 y quiero que cada vez que se cumpla aumente en 1 y se quede así independientemente de lo que pase luego, leiste mal, lo que quiero es que cambie y se mantenga así

Comment: tu variable $var3 siempre va aumentar como dices, se esta definiendo de la misma forma en 0, lo unico que cambia es que al momento de refrescar la pagina tu $var3 tendre tu valor en que se quedo.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es persistir el valor de `$var3` entre peticiones.

Puedes guardar la variable en sesión por ejemplo:

```
<?php
session_start(); # inicia la sesión

$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
// set de var3 antes del condicional, 
// bien 0 cuando accede por primera vez
// o el valor de sesión cuando se repite la llamada
$var3 = (isset($_SESSION['var3']))? $_SESSION['var3'] : 0;

if ($var1 == 1 && $var2 == 2){
    // si es positivo suma uno
    $_SESSION['var3'] = $var3 + 1;
}

print_r([$var1, $var2, $var3]);
```